# Find Maclaurin series and 8-th derivative at $0$ for $ln(4+x^2)$

Tags: taylor-expansion

So I evaluated the Maclaurin series for that and end up with $\sum (-1)^{n-1}\frac{(x^2+3)^{n}}{n}$ and my problem is I have no idea how to get $f^{(8)}(0)$ because of that 3 constant term.

Comment: Rammed it through symbolab and got [this](https://www.symbolab.com/solver/step-by-step/%5Cfrac%7Bd%7D%7Bdx%7D%5Cleft(%5Cfrac%7Bd%7D%7Bdx%7D%5Cleft(%5Cfrac%7Bd%7D%7Bdx%7D%5Cleft(%5Cfrac%7Bd%7D%7Bdx%7D%5Cleft(%5Cfrac%7Bd%7D%7Bdx%7D%5Cleft(%5Cfrac%7Bd%7D%7Bdx%7D%5Cleft(%5Cfrac%7Bd%7D%7Bdx%7D%5Cleft(%5Cleft(%5Cfrac%7Bd%7D%7Bdx%7D%5Cleft(%5Cln%20%5Cleft(4%2Bx%5E%7B2%7D%5Cright)%5Cright)%5Cright)%5Cright)%5Cright)%5Cright)%5Cright)%5Cright)%5Cright)%5Cright))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have not found the Maclaurin series of $\log(4+x^2)$, you have found a power series in $x^2+3$.
The former is given by
$$ f(x)=2\log(2)+\log\left(1+\frac{x^2}{4}\right) = 2\log 2+\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n 4^n} x^{2n} $$
from which it follows that
$$ f^{(8)}(0) = 8!\cdot\frac{(-1)^{4+1}}{4\cdot 4^4} = -\frac{315}{8}.$$